# Storing data using an array,is it good or bad?

Tags: arrays, optimization, storage

So i am making some program that has this function
User comes and open program,and program loads data from his computer,if none,it creates file that will storage data.Now the data is actually an array of class having 5 strings,3 functions and one array of another class(lets call that class class1).That class1 has 1 class(date class i made,containing 3 integers,2 functions) and 3 floating values. That's the data
Its all packed inside static array and its saving it using BinaryFormatter into binary file.That file is loaded on startup again and etc.I tested it and its working but i am scared of what can happen if there are more then 1000 members of array,as its all classes containing more arrays(but those arrays have maximum of 24 members).
RAM Memory on machine doesn't peak over 25 MB,even with 300 members
Processor works well,it works on 1 core only,and while loading,that core goes full load i think,but its very short time,after it reaches 0% usage basically.
Hardware is i5 6600 and Memory is HyperX Savage 8gb,im using m.2 ssd
Maybe that has some effect
Can you tell me if that's good,or should i change something in my code
I would use Data Base but i need it with array inside class,and I don't know how to create that so i used this.

PS: I tested the app and it works instantly fast up to 150 members,after which it slows a bit,but after waiting for RENDERING of labels and buttons for array,it works fast again.

Please help me and give me any advice if its efficient enough for up to 1000-2000 array members.Its written in C#

I have tested it multiple times,and it works,it works ultra fast with less then 150 members in array,i tested with 300 members,and its still fast but there is delay of 2 seconds maybe,up to 4.

Comment: 1000 is basically nothing and you should be able to sort that almost instantly.  If you are really concerned can you store them in the file already sorted?

Comment: Yes,they are already sorted when in file,but i am more worrying of loading them,as it might be a lot and only one thread,i have functions for sorting by name,place where he live and etc,but im scared of it reaching maximum one day and crashing program and that the data will not be recover any more...

Comment: @puhlen im more scared of loading it